# VScode Debugger output not shown

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

So I just Started Learning to code but VS code is acting weird ?

When i run my code in Debug mode the code sometimes does not work.
The code react differently when i ask for
"user input" VS "NOT asking for User Input".

CODE - "NOT asking for User Input"

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    enum Company {
        Google,
        FaceBook,
        XEROX,
        YAHOO,
        EBAY,
        Microsoft
    }COMPANY;
    // int test;
    // scanf("%i", test);
    // printf("%i",test);

    COMPANY = Google;
    printf("%d\n", COMPANY);

    int i;
    for (i= Google; i <= Microsoft; i++)
    {
        printf("%i\n", i);
    };
    return 0;
}
```

Output
[Image of the Debug Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lozPP.png)

CODE - "user input"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    enum Company {
        Google,
        FaceBook,
        XEROX,
        YAHOO,
        EBAY,
        Microsoft
    }COMPANY;
    int test;
    scanf("%i", test);
    printf("%i",test);

    COMPANY = Google;
    printf("%d\n", COMPANY);

    int i;
    for (i= Google; i <= Microsoft; i++)
    {
        printf("%i\n", i);
    };
    return 0;
}
```

Output: [Output for debug console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2Y98.png)

Here is my launch json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%i", test);` ==> `scanf("%i", &test);` enable the compiler warnings! Aside don't use `%i` unless you want to allow the user to enter data in other number bases. If they enter `012` that is octal for ten, not twelve. Better to use `%d`.

Comment: As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, decide for one (!) programming language, see the descriptions of the tags that you applied, too. Further, when you have problems with code, extract a [mcve] first!

Comment: Also, please don't make "progress" updates to the code.

Answer (score 0):

```c
scanf("%i", test);
```

should be

```c
scanf("%i", &test)
```

`scanf()` expect a pointer to int, but you're passing an `int` instead.

Comment: i change that but the issue remains the same

Answer (score 0):

besides the syntax error in the call to `scanf()`

when you enter some value, you have to also enter a 'enter' key so the number is passed through the terminal to the program.

Comment: u mean press Enter ? i did that .
But you see even is a ask it to print out a sentence it does not print it out. Even if the print statement is before the scanf function